# How to make that regular expression for something like "1,3,5,2"?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a regex for this:

```
1
1,1
1,1,1
1,1,1,1
```

the 1's could be any digit (0 to 9)

I guess it would be something like that:

```
/^\d{1}+(,+\d{1})?+(,+\d{1})$/
```

But I don't know how to put that comma in the expression and to make sure there could be a maximum of 4 digits, separated by 3 commas.

Comment: `^\d(?:,\d){0,3}` .. this is not a serious question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this one.

```
/^\d(,\d){0,3}$/
```